# cant play and pause my audio files when pressing play and pressing pause

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

How Do I Get My Play And Pause Button To Work Without J Query?? I Want To Be Able To Click Pause And It Pause.. Click On Play And It Plays.. Here Is What My Codes Look Like..

```
<!-- Music Files -->
    <audio id="id1" src="http://countrydumproductions.com/musics1/site/audio/CDP.ogg"></audio>


<ul class="audio">
    <li><a href="#">Lilly Watson - Right Now</a> <span class="info">(4.4 mb, 491 downloads)</span> <a href="#"> Download</a><div class="cntrls"><a onClick="document.getElementById('id1').pause()" class="pause"></a></a><span class="separator"></span><a onClick="document.getElementById('id1').play()" class="play"></a></a></div></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: add controls attribute to the <audio> element

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTML5 provides you with that functionality. Also it provides you with various other plugins for the audio and video controls. Common ones are jPlayer and jwPlayer.

http://jplayer.org/

and

http://www.jwplayer.com/

You can also check this link for the same purpose.
http://www.alexkatz.me/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/

Comment: So I Have The Player On My Index Page/Main Page That Works Great With A Pause Play Button In One.. But When I Go To My Songs Page I Have Seperate Songs.. At The End Is A Pause Button, And To The Right Of It Is A Play Button.. No Matter What Code I Use It Seems To Not Play Or Pause When I Hit The Buttons.. Ill Keep Searching For Codes But If Anyone Would Like To Help Me Out With A Good Simple Code I Can Add My Own Customized Buttons To It Would Be Much Appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of the thing you have done. Or the development link